# Where-Object and Select -Uniq Causing Conflicting Results

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm retrieving a list of users from Active directory, evaluating them then categorizing them.  The evaluations are simple things like is the `Manager` field empty or not.  After making some evaluations like I mentioned before I separate the 'wrong' objects into an array (when I say 'wrong' I just mean they don't meet the criteria I'm evaluating like the manager field is empty).  The interesting thing is that my array of incorrect objects is not longer accurate, it has added 6 to the total number of objects making it 7.  I validated this by `echo`ing the array and then `echo`ing the `.Length` to see that where I should only have 1 incorrect entry I have 7.  An interesting piece of information is that the other 6 entries are blank as in when I `echo` the array I only see the single entry I expect to see but the length is still 7.

Now I wasn't always getting this behavior, previously I was getting my expected results.  What changed was that I added a `Where-Object` because I needed to exclude an `OU` when I previously didn't.  My `Get-ADUser` statement is currently as follows.

```
$users += Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=workplace,DC=org" -LDAPFilter "(&(SamAccountName=SE*)(!SamAccountName=*SO))" -ResultSetSize 5000 -Properties $properties | Select $properties | Where-Object {$_.distinguishedname -notlike "*,OU=DisabledUsers,*"};
```

The statement itself works fine, I no longer get users from the `OU` I want to omit.  However adding the `Where-Object` seems to conflict with a line I previously had in my script. that line is the following.

```
$incorrectUsers = $incorrectUsers | select -uniq
```

Due to the nature of the evaluations I previously mentioned I would get some User objects appearing more than once which I didn't want happening so I used the `select -uniq` to only see unique items in the array.  But after adding the `Where-Object` I got the discrepancy I listed above.  I then commented out the `select -uniq` above and I got the results I was expecting, 1 incorrect user and the array of incorrect users (`$incorrectUsers`) only has a length of 1.

To me this indicates that there's some conflict between the two statements.  So I'm curious, why does a `Where-Object` and `select -uniq` on an array seem to conflict with one another?

For those curious the `$properties` variable is just an array that contains the following.

```
$properties =
@( 
  'DistinguishedName',
  'SamAccountName',
  'Surname',
  'Givenname',
  'DisplayName',
  'Description',
  'EmailAddress',
  'HomeDrive',
  'HomeDirectory',
  'AccountExpirationDate',
  'Manager'
)
```

Comment: Please show us where `$properties` get defined/assigned (or the entire script even).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well the script itself is rather long but I'll edit the `$properties` into the question.

Comment: In that case, at least attempt to put together a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with which the problem can be reproduced

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen does the explanation of my question not fall under the "Verifiable" section of that link you posted?

Comment: Well, I can't really verify, cause I can't reproduce the issue based on the information you've provided

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well the context of how users got into the `$incorrectUsers` doesn't really matter so you could have populating that list at definition with anything you wanted.  Everything else would have been copied and pasted.  Probably irrelevant now that I figured out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a conflict with the two statements together but rather a conflict with using `select -uniq` on an array with only 1 entry.  I added another user that mimics the one talked about in the question and I was no longer receiving an inflated length.  Because of this I've added an `if` around the statement to only be executed when the length of the array is greater than 1, like so

```
if($incorrectUsers.Length -gt 1){
    $incorrectUsers = $incorrectUsers | select -uniq
}
```